# How can I get the mean of each group in a table - preferebly in bash (awk?

Tags: bash, awk, mean

In bash (maybe awk?) how can I summarize/aggregate a table (like below) to get the mean per group?

```
grp1 1
grp1 3
grp2 5
grp2 8
grp4 9
```

Comment: Since bash does not have fractial arithmetic, you have to switch to a language which does.  If you are happy with usual floating point arithmetic, you could use `awk` or (if you prefer something which more looks like a shell) `zsh`.  If you really need arbitrary precision, [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC19) could be an option, or any language which supports rational arithmetic (Ruby, Haskell, ...) and allows you to do the calculation using fractional numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do this in `awk` :

```
awk '{sum[$1]+=$2; count[$1]++} END {for(key in sum) print key ":  " sum[key]/count[key]}' input_file
```

Output for your sample file :

```
grp1: 2
grp2: 6.5
grp4: 9
```

Explanation :

- `{sum[$1]+=$2; count[$1]++}` : for every line of your input file, we use 2 associative arrays

  - `count` that stores the number of time the 1st field is encountered
  - `sum` that stores the sum of every value for the 2nd field for this specific group
- `END {for(key in sum) print key ":  " sum[key]/count[key]}` : when your file has finished parsing, we print every group, as well as the `sum/count` for this group

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat file
grp1 1
grp1 3
grp2 5
grp2 8
grp4 9
    

awk '{d[$1]+=$2; cnt[$1]++} END{for (e in d) print e, d[e] / cnt[e]}' file
```

Prints:

```
grp1 2
grp2 6.5
grp4 9
```

Of if you want them all to be floating point presentation:

```
awk '{d[$1]+=$2; cnt[$1]++} END{for (e in d) printf("%s %0.2f\n", e, d[e] / cnt[e])}'
```

Prints:

```
grp1 2.00
grp2 6.50
grp4 9.00
```

Know that associative arrays in awk do not maintain order so the `grpX` may change from the order found in the file.